# How to 'union' 2 or more DataTables in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

How to 'union' 2 or more DataTables in C#?

Both table has same structure.

Is there any build-in function or should we do manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking most likely for the [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) method.

**Example**:

```
private static void DemonstrateMergeTable()
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Items");

    // Add columns
    DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32));
    DataColumn itemColumn = new DataColumn("item", typeof(System.Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add(idColumn);
    table1.Columns.Add(itemColumn);

    // Set the primary key column.
    table1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { idColumn };

    // Add RowChanged event handler for the table.
    table1.RowChanged += new 
        System.Data.DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);

    // Add ten rows.
    DataRow row;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        row = table1.NewRow();
        row["id"] = i;
        row["item"] = i;
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    // Accept changes.
    table1.AcceptChanges();
    PrintValues(table1, "Original values");

    // Create a second DataTable identical to the first.
    DataTable table2 = table1.Clone();

    // Add column to the second column, so that the 
    // schemas no longer match.
    table2.Columns.Add("newColumn", typeof(System.String));

    // Add three rows. Note that the id column can't be the 
    // same as existing rows in the original table.
    row = table2.NewRow();
    row["id"] = 14;
    row["item"] = 774;
    row["newColumn"] = "new column 1";
    table2.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table2.NewRow();
    row["id"] = 12;
    row["item"] = 555;
    row["newColumn"] = "new column 2";
    table2.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table2.NewRow();
    row["id"] = 13;
    row["item"] = 665;
    row["newColumn"] = "new column 3";
    table2.Rows.Add(row);

    // Merge table2 into the table1.
    Console.WriteLine("Merging");
    table1.Merge(table2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    PrintValues(table1, "Merged With table1, schema added");

}

private static void Row_Changed(object sender, 
    DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row changed {0}\t{1}", e.Action, 
        e.Row.ItemArray[0]);
}

private static void PrintValues(DataTable table, string label)
{
    // Display the values in the supplied DataTable:
    Console.WriteLine(label);
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write("\t " + row[col].ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
public static DataTable Union (DataTable First, DataTable Second)
{

      //Result table
      DataTable table = new DataTable("Union");

      //Build new columns
      DataColumn[] newcolumns = new DataColumn[First.Columns.Count];

      for(int i=0; i < First.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          newcolumns[i] = new DataColumn(
          First.Columns[i].ColumnName, First.Columns[i].DataType);
      }

      table.Columns.AddRange(newcolumns);
      table.BeginLoadData();

      foreach(DataRow row in First.Rows)
      {
           table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray,true);
      }

      foreach(DataRow row in Second.Rows)
      {
          table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray,true);
      }

      table.EndLoadData();
      return table;
}
```

From [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/archive/2004/01/15/724.aspx) (not tested).

Comment: Maybe he wants also to take into account the case when both DataTables have a matching record (same values for all columns)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Concat from Linq to datasets (get the free chapter of LINQ in Action) to join them and then .AsDataTable to create the table (assuming you actually want them as a DataTable)

Comment: LINQ is like the jQuery of the .NET data access universe, it is the answer to everything.

Comment: @LazyBoy: you will be soon (seriously though, the chapter of the book goes through the System.Data.DataSetExtensions assembly and the afforances it offers that extend DataSets to offer even more power than DataSets already offer (and with that convoluted power...)).  @TheTXI: If it can't be done by sprinklingh in some PS and some LINQ, what's the point :D

Comment: The point of my comment being that you can union two tables in a single line with LINQ using the functions I cite (assuming there is at least one row in the combined result...)

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this question, and Ruben Bartelink gave a great answer, but with no code.  So I had to look it up elsewhere, which defeats the point of StackOverflow.  Now that it's 2010, the other answers given aren't quite as viable.  For reference, here's code demonstrating the CopyToDataTable() extension method.  It's in VB so as to not steal the credit from Ruben if he wants to revisit the past and post a more complete answer :)

```
Public Function GetSchema(ByVal dbNames As IEnumerable(Of String)) As DataTable
   Dim schemaTables As New List(Of DataTable)()
   For Each dbName As String In dbNames
      Dim cnnStr = GetConnectionString(dbName)
      Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(cnnStr)
      cnn.Open()
      Dim dt = cnn.GetSchema("Columns")
      cnn.Close()
      schemaTables.Add(dt)
   Next

   Dim dtResult As DataTable = Nothing
   For Each dt As DataTable In schemaTables
      If dtResult Is Nothing Then
         dtResult = dt
      Else
         dt.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable(dtResult, LoadOption.PreserveChanges)
      End If
   Next

   Return dtResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Linq to DataSet, must add the reference for System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, another approach, alternative for DataTable.Merge method).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoUnion();
}

private static void DoUnion()
{
    DataTable table1 = GetProducts();
    DataTable table2 = NewProducts();
    var tbUnion = table1.AsEnumerable()
        .Union(table2.AsEnumerable());
    DataTable unionTable = table1.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow fruit in tbUnion)
    {
        var fruitValue = fruit.Field<string>(0);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}->{1}", fruit.Table, fruitValue);
        DataRow row = unionTable.NewRow();
        row.SetField<string>(0, fruitValue);
        unionTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

private static DataTable NewProducts()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("CitricusTable");
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("product", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(col);
    string[] citricusFruits = { "Orange", "Grapefruit", "Lemon", "Lime", "Tangerine" };
    foreach (string fruit in citricusFruits)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row.SetField<string>(col, fruit);
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}

private static DataTable GetProducts()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("MultipleFruitsTable");
    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("product", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(col);
    string[] multipleFruits = { "Breadfruit", "Custardfruit", "Jackfruit", "Osage-orange", "Pineapple" };
    foreach (string fruit in multipleFruits)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row.SetField<string>(col, fruit);
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

antonio