# C# Data table how to concat two tables rows vertically using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How to concat rows vertically from two tables using linq, i already written a query for that but it adding next to first row hence i'm getting columns count double but i want to concat by next row.

```
var dd4 = from tbl in dataTb.AsEnumerable()
                      join dpi in rawDataTable.AsEnumerable() on tbl["Account_No"] equals dpi["Account_No"]
                      select tbl.ItemArray.Concat(dpi.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

It giving me structure like

col1 col2 col3.... col24 but my table having only 12 columns so it adding next to it but how can i add after 12 column end then new row should be start.

dataTb table data:

```
chNo Chunit  val1  val2  val3 val4
 1    kwh    2010  2011  2012 2009
 2    kvarh  2012  2011  2008 2009
```

rawDataTable data:

```
chNo Chunit  val1  val2  val3 val4
 1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
 2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
```

It's adding like this:

```
1    kwh    2010  2011  2012 2009  1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
1    kwh    2010  2011  2012 2009  2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
2    kvarh  2012  2011  2008 2009  1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
2    kvarh  2012  2011  2008 2009  2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
```

but i want like this:

```
1    kwh    2010  2011  2012 2009
1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
2    kvarh  2012  2011  2008 2009
1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
```

currently 'm getting: but want like above (For Yograj)

```
1    kwh    2010  2011  2012 2009
2    kvarh  2012  2011  2008 2009
1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
1    kw     2.2   2.1   2.1  2.0
2    kvar   1.2   1.1   1.1  1.0
```

Thanks,
@nag.

Comment: Could your give sample input and expected output?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to get? Show data in rawDataTable and show what data you want to get.

Comment: Why dont you try `DataTable.Merge`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/920521/293712

Comment: @CuongLe can you please check my updated post.

Comment: @YograjGupta But here i'm querying on rows right? so how merge 'll happen here?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Can you please check my updated post.

Comment: I still dont understand the rule why 6 rows in output? why not 4 rows?

Comment: @nag: may be you need to use `Union`

Comment: Do you want to get groups of values? or this is plane datatable with dublicates?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Yeah duplicates can exist from second table not in first table so kwh and kvarh should have only one no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this query

```
var dd4 = from tbl in dataTb.AsEnumerable()
          join dpi in rawDataTable.AsEnumerable() 
          on tbl["Account_No"] equals dpi["Account_No"]
          select new {datarows = new []{ tbl, dpi}};

var resultDataTable = dd4.SelectMany(x=>x.datarows).CopyToDataTable();
```

You can achieve duplicate from second but not from first.

```
var resultDataTable = dd4.Select(x=>x.datarows.First()).Distinct()
                      .Concat(dd4.Select(x=>x.datarows.Last()))
                      .CopyToDataTable();
```

Try this for your desired output

```
var records = from x in dd4
              group x by x.datarows.First() into y
              select y;

List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();

foreach(var item in records)
{
   rows.Add(item.Key);
   rows.AddRange(item.ToList().Select(x=>x.datarows.Last()));
}

var resultDataTable = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Hope It will help.

Comment: its working but it having duplicates kwh and kvarh two times but i want only one how to ignore it?

Comment: No it's applying on all rows but i need to have only one kwh and one kvarh.

Comment: It'll getting distinct rows of first table but 'm loosing second table duplicate values also.

Comment: hey i posted above after i applied your query how it'll giving me results and check my edited post

Comment: And your updated distinct query won't working fine its removing second table duplicates also, but i need them.

Comment: @nag try this `dd4.Select(x=>x.datarows.First()).Distinct().Concat(dd4.Select(x=>x.datarows.Last())).CopyToDataTable()` It will include the duplicates of second.

Comment: I updated my post with result giving after applied your above logic.

Comment: Yeah i'm getting but is this only way to get desired output no other short way or combined with single query?