# how to store multiple datatable into a single dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have multiple datatable. I want to show all the datatable rows into a single gridview.
How can I do that?

```
DataTable dtbag101 = (DataTable)Session["bag101"];
DataTable dtwallet111 = (DataTable)Session["wallet111"];


DataSet ds= new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dtbag101);
ds.Tables.Add(dtwallet111);

GridView1.DataSource= ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The column names for both datatable are the same.
Here I was trying to use dataset but only first DataTable i.e. datbag101 was showing in the gridview.

How can I show all the values in one gridview?

Comment: hey try this once [**`DataTable.Merge`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wfzxak4(vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use [**DataTable.Merge**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkk7s5zk.aspx)

```
DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();
dtAll = dtbag101 .Copy();
dtAll.Merge(dtwallet111, true);
GridView1.DataSource= dtAll;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

*Edit to show how it should work*

```
private void BindGridWithMergeTables()
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

    dt1.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt2.Columns.Add("ID");

    DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
    DataRow dr2 = dt2.NewRow();

    dr1["ID"] = "1";
    dr2["ID"] = "2";
    dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
    dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);

    DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();
    dtAll = dt1.Copy();
    dtAll.Merge(dt2, true);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtAll;
    dataGridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: i want to show all the value at a time.. it was showing only one again. @Adil

Comment: no merge method is not working. can you tell me other method or process?? @Adil

Comment: It should work, I made an example for you and added in question.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your two data tables have the same columns, you can UNION them with some handy LINQ.

```
DataTable dtbag101 = (DataTable)Session["bag101"];
DataTable dtwallet111 = (DataTable)Session["wallet111"];

var result = dtbag101.AsEnumerable().Union(dtwallet111.AsEnumerable());

GridView1.DataSource = result;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Otherwise try use `DataTable.Merge`:

```
DataTable dtbag101 = (DataTable)Session["bag101"];
DataTable dtwallet111 = (DataTable)Session["wallet111"];

dtbag101.Merge(dtwallet111, true);

GridView1.DataSource = dtbag101;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working for you.  Try this method (grabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920505/how-to-union-2-or-more-datatables-in-c)):

```
public static DataTable Union(DataTable First, DataTable Second)
{
      //Result table
      DataTable table = new DataTable("Union");

      //Build new columns
      DataColumn[] newcolumns = new DataColumn[First.Columns.Count];

      for(int i=0; i < First.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          newcolumns[i] = new DataColumn(
          First.Columns[i].ColumnName, First.Columns[i].DataType);
      }

      table.Columns.AddRange(newcolumns);
      table.BeginLoadData();

      foreach(DataRow row in First.Rows)
      {
           table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray,true);
      }

      foreach(DataRow row in Second.Rows)
      {
          table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray,true);
      }

      table.EndLoadData();
      return table;
}
```

Call the method with your two datatables:

```
GridView1.DataSource = Union(dtbag101, dtwallet111);
```

Comment: Updated answer with `DataTable.Merge`.

Comment: no sir only showing gridview header text. but no data is showing. i am trying Merge method.

Comment: Are you sure that your second datatable even has data?  Try this to find out:  `GridView1.DataSource = dtwallet111;`

Comment: first i was not used correct cmd format thats why it was not working.. sorry and thanks..

Comment: now if only one datatable is available at a time then it is not showing anything. how can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **[`DataTable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wfzxak4%28vs.71%29.aspx)** method

```
DataTable dtbag101 = (DataTable)Session["bag101"];
DataTable dtwallet111 = (DataTable)Session["wallet111"];

dtbag101.Merge(dtwallet111);  //Merge action

GridView1.DataSource= dtbag101;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I dont know much about this. Just referred it now.

**or else**

try for loop

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
addTables(dtbag101);
addTables(dtwallet111); //ds will be merge of both tables here
```

---

```
private void addTables(DataTable dt)
{
   for(int intCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount < dt.Rows.Count;intCount++)
   {
       for(int intSubCount = 0;intSubCount < dt.Columns.Count; intSubCount++)
       {
          ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][intSubCount] = dt.Rows[intCount][intSubCount];
       }
   }
}
```